# Are there free secure ways to audit a LAMP's security configs?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, lamp, audit

Problem is new to LAMP, and want to test the system config in any automated checklist way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bastille Linux](http://bastille-linux.sourceforge.net/) comes to mind.

It's not LAMP specific as such, but is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

There's another [PHP config security audit tool](http://php-security-audit.com/scripts/view/php_security.php) which you might find useful (and I'd appreciate any suggestions you might have for it :)

Comment: **@danlefree:** Have a very limited knowledge of PHP, what does the code do?

Comment: @blunders - It tests to determine whether functions which an attacker would use are enabled (i.e. test whether remote file includes are enabled, test whether your PHP config allows a script to issue shell commands, etc) - the audit tool won't do anything malicious, but the idea is based upon a remote include file I've seen a would-be hacker try :)

Comment: **@danlefree:** So, haven't found anyone else to look at the code, but did see one thing that puzzled me. get_current_user would not equal PHP's system rights, correct, nor would PHP ever be root. Am I missing something?

Comment: @blunders - It's *possible* to run PHP and Apache under the root account - figured it'd be worth warning about if encountered :)

Comment: **@danlefree:** Ended up not using it, just to hard (for me) to tell what it's doing. Did post this question, though and it appear to be an ok script... :-) ...again, thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987631/want-to-audit-my-php-security-will-this-php-harm-modifiy-etc-my-system-if-run